# Doubles Round Robin Sorting Algorithm

Tags: sorting

Background:  I have a group of 6 guys that get together and play pickleball every week.  We play 2v2 and 2 players sit each game.  We play 2 sets of 6 games each week (12 total games) - in each set, each player plays 4 games, and sits for 2 games.  At the end of each set, each player totals up the amount of points he scores, and we have a winner.

Anyway, I worked out all the combinations of games for 6 people for playing doubles.  There are a total of 45 unique games that could be played, where every combination of partners would play every other combination of partners.  I would like to come up with a schedule to play all 45 of these games across 4 sessions of 2 sets each for a total of 8 sets (the final 3 games in the last set can be arbitrary since 6x8=48, and there are only 45 unique games).

The problem comes in with determining the order of the games, such that following criteria is met, for each of the sets of 6 games:

1. Each player plays 4 games, and sits for 2 games.
2. No player sits for 2 consecutive games.
3. Each player partners with a different partner every game.  (i.e. no 2 players partner more than once per set).

Where I could use help is figuring out the algorithm to come up with the optimal order of games.  With 45 factorial possible orders ~1e56...it's too many to brute force.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
All the combinations for players A, B, C, D, E, and F:
T1  T2  Bye
AB  CD  EF
AB  CE  DF
AB  CF  DE
AB  DE  CF
AB  DF  CE
AB  EF  CD
AC  BD  EF
AC  BE  DF
AC  BF  DE
AC  DE  BF
AC  DF  BE
AC  EF  BD
AD  BC  EF
AD  BE  CF
AD  BF  CE
AD  CE  BF
AD  CF  BE
AD  EF  BC
AE  BC  DF
AE  BD  CF
AE  BF  CD
AE  CD  BF
AE  CF  BD
AE  DF  BC
AF  BC  DE
AF  BD  CE
AF  BE  CD
AF  CD  BE
AF  CE  BD
AF  DE  BC
BC  DE  AF
BC  DF  AE
BC  EF  AD
BD  CE  AF
BD  CF  AE
BD  EF  AC
BE  CD  AF
BE  CF  AD
BE  DF  AC
BF  CD  AE
BF  CE  AD
BF  DE  AC
CD  EF  AB
CE  DF  AB
CF  DE  AB
```

Tried writing a brute force algorithm in Excel VBA...seems like it was going to take forever to run.

Comment: Since this is not really about programming but about how to solve an assignment problem, I suggest asking at https://or.stackexchange.com instead, where you're much more likely to get helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  It's really not a homework problem...just an old guy who isn't good at programming...

Comment: When I said "assignment problem" I was referring to the optimisation problem usually called "assignment problem", not to a problem that was assigned to you as homework. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem (although this wikipedia article talks mostly about the particular case when the problem constraints are all linear; your problem appears to contain quadratic constraints). These kinds of problems are extremely common in the field known as "operations research", which is why I'm suggesting asking the question at https://or.stackexchange.com

Comment: The word "assignment" simply refers to the fact that you're assigning players to seats.